# If any linear function $f:E→Q$ is $0$ then $E=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and consider $a_1,...,a_n$ elements of $\mathbb{F}$ such that $a_i\neq a_j$ if $i\neq j$. Let $E=Span_\mathbb{Q}\{a_1,...,a_n\}$.
>
> Show that if any linear function $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is $0$ then, since $char(\mathbb{F})=0$, $E=0$.

I have some problems proving it:

I tried to solve it by observing that if $char(\mathbb{F})=0$ it is well defined the linear function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$f(q_1a_1+...+q_na_n)=q_1+...+q_n$$
which is $0$ iff $a_1=...=a_n=0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Any non-zero vector space has a non-zero linear functional (for example choose a basis and define the functional to be $1$ on the first basis vector and $0$ else). Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also this means we don't need to ask for char(F)=0?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't need characteristic $0$. However it would be interesting to know the line of thought of the author.

Comment: The statement is trivially false. Why? because "if *any* $f \equiv 0$, then $E = 0$" means $((\exists f)f \equiv 0) \implies E = 0$. which is obviously false since every $E$ has the $0$ functional. What the statement should say is "if *every* $f \equiv 0$, then $E = 0$".